# How do I set a column in SQL Server to varchar(max) using ASP.net EF Codefirst Data Annotations?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've been searching around the web trying to figure out the right syntax to have Entity Framework Code First create my table with a column: varchar(max).

This is what I have. By default this creates varchar(128). How do I create varchar(max)?

I have tried [MaxLength] without success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
public string MediaDesc { get; set; }
```

Comment: `[Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]` works for me. But I get a `varchar(8000)` with your code snippet, not `varchar(128)` as you say. Strange. What EF version are you using and what database version?

Comment: Thanks Slauma. Figures I tried a bunch of different ways except the most obvious. Works like a charm!

Comment: If you submit this as an answer I will accept. Thx again!

Comment: I was actually surprised that it works :) (I'll write it as answer then...)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
```

Surprisingly the most obvious solution works.

The `[MaxLength]` attribute only creates a `varchar` column with a max length that isn't MAX but - in my case (SQL Server Express 2008 R2) - 8000.

Comment: **alter column size using database first method**:, i used this in sql to change size from nvarchar(50) to max:
`alter table Product alter column WebSite nvarchar(max) null`

Note: this will not effect the model property, but if you alter the column name to new name then it will effect the model with error, then you can use option 'update model from databse' or delete the `.edmx` file and recreate it. Hope helps someone.

Comment: For MAX string length it works fine but if you want to mention specific string length in-line then it starts to fail.   This    [Column("ToDoItem", TypeName = "nvarchar(2000)")] will not work and fails with really mysterious errors which gives you no clue of what is going wrong behind the scenes. For MAX nvarchar length you don't need to mention the stringLength attribute separately. I'm on EF 6 btw.

Comment: I had to tell it the name of the column, because it was inconsistent with my Property name :  `[Column("BUS_UNIT", TypeName="varchar(MAX)")]` even though property was named `BusUnit1`

Answer (score 21):

This will get you `nvarchar(max)`:

```
[StringLength(int.MaxValue)]
```

I don't think there's an attribute to force non-unicode (are you sure you want that?), so for `varchar(max)` you need a tweak in the DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(x => x.MediaDesc).IsUnicode(false);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `int.MaxInt` works for the `StringLength` attribute? I tried this with the `MaxLength` attribute (`[StringLength(int.MaxInt)]`) and get an exception that the value must not be greater than 4000. Maybe it works with `StringLength`, but if so, then that's all very confusing...

Comment: No idea about MaxLength. I tried with StringLength, and it works as expected.

Comment: I just found that the combination with the `[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]` attribute is the problem. Without it works with `MaxLength` and `StringLength` as well. +1

Comment: I think using `MaxLength` is most idiomatic (and concise), but both `StringLength` and `MaxLength` are far better than specifying the column type name explicitly, as the accepted answer does.

Comment: 1.  Here is the "Fluent" : /* Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<MyCustomEntity> builder */
            builder.Property(ml => ml.MyBigStringScalarProperty).HasMaxLength(Int32.MaxValue);   and (2) I prefer this answer.  I have to support MsSqlServer and Postgres...and I have verified (my fluent style at least) gives (the MsSqlServer desired behavior) AND the the postgres equivalent of (ddl column) "MyBigStringScalarProperty TEXT".  Thanks Deigo.

Answer (score 4):

Use  [MaxLength] annotation.

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
[MaxLength]
public string MediaDesc { get; set; }
```

Comment: For me this creates a `varchar(8000)` column, not `varchar(MAX)`.

Comment: MaxLength is a validation, not a column definition

Answer (score 3):

Update for @Slauma answer.

Using a override for all strings like this in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(s => 
    s.HasMaxLength(256).HasColumnType("nvarchar"));
```

and then modifying properties with attributes like this:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
public string CaseComment { get; set; }
```

Or this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourClass>()
    .Property(b => b.CaseComment)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");
```

This can cause the Exception. `Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.` Even though the column is of correct data type Entity Framework still thinks it is `nvarchar(256)` and throws the error `DbEntityValidationException`.

To fix this use the following instead:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
[MaxLength]
public string CaseComment { get; set; }
```

Or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourClass>()
    .Property(b => b.CaseComment)
    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")
    .HasMaxLength(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]` results in varchar(Max) in the database.  If you have a custom convention setting strings MaxLength to 100,

```
modelBuilder
    .Properties<string>()
    .Configure(c => c.IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(100));
```

you need to include the MaxLength attribute `[Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)"), MaxLength]`.  If you don't, you will get varchar(MAX) in the database but validation will throw for more than 100 characters.