# How to update nvarchar(max) field to XML datatype using EF6 migrations, for data optimization

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

**Background**

I have a service running that reads XML output from an API, provided by a supplier of ours. It's an xml that can be of varying file size.

I'm using EF6 code-first migrations, via attribute mapping, to generate the database. The entity is defined like this:

```
[Table("DataUploadEvents")]
public class DataUploadEvent
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string RawData { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

As-is the raw xml data is stored, but when querying the data is truncated, even though the files aren't really that large (not even close to the 2 GB limit of `nvarchar(max)`). Files larger than 2 MB are rare.

I can set my Sql Server Management Studio client to [not truncate result sets](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2795/prevent-truncation-of-dynamically-generated-results-in-sql-server-management-studio/), but that's likely not what I want (not performant).

**What I tried**

I tried changing the RawData field to type XElement and XDocument, but then I get this error on adding a new migration:

> EntityType 'XElement' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.

**Question**

> What do I need to do to ensure that my RawData field is changed to SQL
>   XML DataType?

**Update**

If I cast my RawData field to xml datatype:

```
SELECT CAST([RawData] as xml) FROM [DataUploadEvents]
```

I *do* get the full xml content. So as suspected the data isn't truncated on write, but on read (which I can by-pass this way).

Comment: `when querying the data is truncated` that's a problem with the querying code then. Changing the data type won't fix this. `set my Sql Server Management Studio client to ..` that has nothing to do with EF or the database. SSMS is just a client tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I set a column in SQL Server to varchar(max) using ASP.net EF Codefirst Data Annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235847/how-do-i-set-a-column-in-sql-server-to-varcharmax-using-asp-net-ef-codefirst-d) The simple answer is: `[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Incorrect, that's not the question.

Comment: What *is* the question? EF Core *doesn't* truncate long text rows. If the results come truncated you need to fix *that* problem, not change the type only to find *another* problem - how will you read that field? What about storage?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The question is: change FROM nvarchar(max) to XML, to try and see if the data is still truncated like that in "Sql Server Management Studio client".

Comment: And as I explained, SSMS has *nothing at all* to do with this - that's a setting in a some other client application that doesn't affect how SQL Server works. Changing the type won't automagically fixed the unrelated truncation problem. Are you *sure* the data wasn't stored truncated to begin with? Did you check the generated SQL query? What does it look like? What happens when you execute that query directly, do you get the full results? How big are the returned strings anyway? Are all of them truncated at the same point?